# How to get number of iteratoins of pcl Iterative Closest Point (ICP)?

Tags: c++, iteration, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I´m trying different variants of the Iterative Closest Point (ICP) Algorithm from the pcl library. And I want to compare time, error and number of iterations.

Time is easy (just measuring before and after the algorithm), error is provided by the `getFitnessScore()` method from the icp class.

But how do I get the number of iterations???

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that it is not implemented to get the number of iterations:
http://www.pcl-users.org/ICP-number-of-iterations-td4038888.html#a4038894